# Simple java program with scanner error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Ok - so this is a very simple java program. I keep getting the following error. After reading the docs, I have made sure all my scanner statements are coded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
Enter working hours: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at WeeklyWages.main(WeeklyWages.java:12)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WeeklyWages {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double hrsworked, payrate, wages;

        System.out.print("Enter working hours: ");
        hrsworked = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the payrate: ");
        payrate = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        if (hrsworked > 40)
            wages = 40.0 * payrate + 1.5 * payrate * (hrsworked - 40.0);
        else
            wages = hrsworked * payrate;

        System.out.printf("Hours worked = .2%f %n", wages);
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the input you are testing it with?

Comment: I can't input anything - I just get that error

Comment: It sounds like something is screwing with stdin.  How are you invoking the program?  Do you get the same error when you run it from the command line as from in an IDE?

Comment: @azurefrog you were right - did it via CMD and it worked. Something wrong with Sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like something wrong with Sublimetext. I just compiled it via javac in dos and it worked. weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your Syntax wrong and does not imported library "java.util.scanner"
Here is the proper code for you

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainPrintThread {

```
public static void main(String args[])

{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);



        double hrsworked, payrate, wages;

        System.out.print("Enter working hours: ");
        hrsworked = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the payrate: ");
        payrate = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        if (hrsworked > 40)
            wages = 40.0 * payrate + 1.5 * payrate * (hrsworked - 40.0);
        else
            wages = hrsworked * payrate;

        System.out.printf("Hours worked = .2%f %n", wages);
        System.out.println();

    }



}
```